# Wazuh syscheck agent SQL error on centos7: FIM is not working

Tags: centos7, wazuh

I havd wazuh v3.13.3 installed on centos 7.
syscheck module configuration:

```
  <syscheck>
    <disabled>no</disabled>

    <!-- Frequency that syscheck is executed default every 12 hours -->
    <frequency>43200</frequency>

    <scan_on_start>yes</scan_on_start>
    <alert_new_files>yes</alert_new_files>


    <!-- Directories to check  (perform all possible verifications) -->
    <directories check_all="yes">/etc,/usr/bin,/usr/sbin</directories>
    <directories check_all="yes">/bin,/sbin,/boot</directories>
    <directories check_all="yes" realtime="yes">/root</directories>

    <!-- Files/directories to ignore -->
    <ignore>/etc/mtab</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/hosts.deny</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/mail/statistics</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/random-seed</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/random.seed</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/adjtime</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/httpd/logs</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/utmpx</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/wtmpx</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/cups/certs</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/dumpdates</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/svc/volatile</ignore>
    <ignore>/sys/kernel/security</ignore>
    <ignore>/sys/kernel/debug</ignore>
    <ignore>/dev/core</ignore>

    <!-- File types to ignore -->
    <ignore type="sregex">^/proc</ignore>
    <ignore type="sregex">.log$|.swp$</ignore>

    <!-- Check the file, but never compute the diff -->
    <nodiff>/etc/ssl/private.key</nodiff>

    <skip_nfs>yes</skip_nfs>
  </syscheck>
```

Adding new file to the /root directory:

```
[root@host ossec]# date; echo "date" >  ~/newfile.txt
Sat May  7 17:01:48 UTC 2022
```

agent log messages:

```
2022/05/07 17:01:48 ossec-syscheckd[26052] fim_db.c:558 at fim_db_exec_simple_wquery(): ERROR: SQL ERROR: cannot commit - no transaction is active
2022/05/07 17:01:48 ossec-syscheckd[26052] fim_db.c:558 at fim_db_exec_simple_wquery(): ERROR: SQL ERROR: cannot commit - no transaction is active
2022/05/07 17:01:48 ossec-syscheckd[26052] fim_db.c:558 at fim_db_exec_simple_wquery(): ERROR: SQL ERROR: cannot commit - no transaction is active
2022/05/07 17:01:48 ossec-syscheckd: ERROR: SQL ERROR: (8)attempt to write a readonly database
2022/05/07 17:01:48 ossec-syscheckd: ERROR: SQL ERROR: (8)attempt to write a readonly database
```

and I see no messages about new file in the logs.

It is too big infrastructure to upgrade to wazuh 4.x

How to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The message `ERROR: SQL ERROR: (8)attempt to write a readonly database` indicates some kind of problem with database permissions or that the FIM database `fim.db` does not exist, please check that the following files in the agent exist and have the following permissions, user, and group:

```
[drwxr-x--- ossec    ossec   ]  /var/ossec/queue/fim 
[drwxr-x--- ossec    ossec   ]  /var/ossec/queue/fim/db 
[-rw-rw---- root     ossec   ]  /var/ossec/queue/fim/db/fim.db 
[-rw-rw---- root     ossec   ]  /var/ossec/queue/fim/db/fim.db-journal
```

- In case the `fim.db` file does not exist, the agent recreates said file when restarting the agent.
- In case the `fim/` or `fim/db/` directories do not exist, it is necessary to create them using the `mkdir` command and assign them the properties specified above `[drwxr-x--- ossec ossec]`, then restart the agent.